# Default post_tag for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, tags, terms

Is there a way to set a default `post_tag` to all posts within a custom post type.

I would like all my posts from a custom posts type assigned to one tag displayed in the `wp_tag_cloud`. Is there a way to implement `wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append )` in the args for registering post type

Example from wp codex:

```
function codex_book_init() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Books', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Book', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'          => _x( 'Books', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Book', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Books:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No books found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No books found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
            'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
);

register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the taxonomy `post_tag` to your custom post type, you need to set the `taxonomies` parameter in your arguments when registering your post type

> **`taxonomies`**
>
> (array) (optional) An array of registered taxonomies like `category` or `post_tag` that will be used with this post type. This can be used in lieu of calling `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` directly. Custom taxonomies still need to be registered with `register_taxonomy()`.
>
> Default: no taxonomies

So you would add something like this in your arguments

```
'taxonomies' => ['post_tag'],
```

You will now have the tag meta box in your custom post type post page.

If you need to set a specific tag to all posts, you can run a custom query to get all the posts you need to alter, and then use `wp_set_object_terms()` on each post to set the specific tag

You can try the following: (*Requires PHP 5.4+. Also, backup your database before running this query. You can run this once and remove it*)

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // If you need all posts, set according to needs
    'fields' => 'ids', // Only get post ID's, very lean query
    // Add any other paramaters according to need
];
$q = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $q as $post ) {
    if (    term_exists( 'MY_TAG', 'post_tag' ) 
         && !has_tag( 'MY TAG', $post ) 
    ) // Only run if the tag is not yet assigned and if it exists
        wp_set_object_terms( 
            $post, // Post ID 
            'MY TAG', // Term to add, tag in this case 
            'post_tag', // Taxonomy the term belongs to
            true // Append the tag, don't replace tags
        );
}
```

Comment: Any feedback on this issue?